# Changing information in a CSV file

Tags: ruby, csv

I'm trying to write a ruby script that will read through a CSV file and prepend information to certain cells (for instance adding a path to a file). I am able to open and mutate the text just fine, but am having issues writing back to the CSV without overriding everything. This is a sample of what I have so far:

```
CSV.foreach(path) { |row|
    text = row[0].to_s
    new_text = "test:#{text}"
}
```

I would like to add something within that block that would then write `new_text`back to the same reference cell(`row`) in the file. The only way I have to found to write to a file is

```
 CSV.open(path, "wb") { |row|
     row << new_text
 }
```

But I think that is bad practice since you are reopening the file within the file block already. Is there a better way I could do this?

EX: I have a CSV file that looks something like:

```
file,destination
test.txt,A101
```

and need it to be:

```
file,destination
path/test.txt,id:A101
```

Hope that makes sense. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the size if the file, you might consider loading the contents of the file into a local variable and then manipulating that, overwriting the original file.

```
lines = CSV.read(path)

File.open(path, "wb") do |file|
  lines.each do |line|
    text = line[0].to_s
    line[0] = "test:#{text}" # Replace this with your editing logic
    file.write CSV.generate_line(line)
  end
end
```

Alternately, if the file is big, you could write each modified line to a new file along the way and then replace the old file with the new one at the end.

Comment: I had thought about doing something like that, but didn't think to use `File` over `CSV`. I think that will get me going thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Given that you don't appear to be doing anything that draws on CSV capabilities, I'd recommend using Ruby's "in-place" option variable [`$-i`](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ruby-doc-bundle/Manual/man-1.4/variable.html#opt_i).

Some of the stats software I use wants just the data, and can't deal with a header line.  Here's a script I wrote a while back to (appear to) strip the first line out of one or more data files specified on the command-line.

```
#! /usr/bin/env ruby -w
#
# User supplies the name of one or more files to be "stripped"
# on the command-line.
#
# This script ignores the first line of each file.
# Subsequent lines of the file are copied to the new version.
#
# The operation saves each original input file with a suffix of
# ".orig" and then operates in-place on the specified files.

$-i = ".orig"   # specify backup suffix

oldfilename = ""

ARGF.each do |line|
  if ARGF.filename == oldfilename   # If it's an old file
    puts line                       # copy lines through.
  else                              # If it's a new file remember it
    oldfilename = ARGF.filename     # but don't copy the first line.
  end
end
```

Obviously you'd want to change the `puts line` pass-through to whatever edit operations you want to perform.

I like this solution because even if you screw it up, you've preserved your original file as its original name with `.orig` (or whatever suffix you choose) appended.